# How to insert data into mysql table having column name as number

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table whose columns are like: **s_no**, **prop**, **room**, **price**, **date**, **1**, **2**, … , **30**.

Now when I am inserting data into the column named 28. through PHP, I am recieving this error:

> SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '28='120' where s_no='10''

How do I insert data into this column?

Comment: **1**,**2**......**30** column name??? any reason to using like that?? but u still need to share your code, because column name is not an issue u have syntax error in your query.

Comment: Give your columns sensible alphbetic names

Comment: Alternatively wrap all the dumb column names in backticks like `\`1\``

Comment: `Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.` -http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: If someone is facing this, I added the wrong name column as ´26´, it has to be \`26\`

Answer (score 3):

According to [MariaDB's Identifiers Names reference](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/identifier-names/) :

> Identifiers may be quoted using the backtick character - `. Quoting is optional for identifiers that don't contain special characters, or is a reserved word.

You should wrap the columns names with ``` `` ```:

```
`28` = '...'
```

> However I really recommend changing your schema to have meaningful colum names

Comment: Thanks a lot. it's working now..

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using back ticks

```
UPDATE table SET `30`='100' WHERE id='1'
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly the answer the I already gave 1 hour ago?

Comment: can't you see i written query ?

Comment: thank you. it's working now..